# Finding String permuatations

Tags: permutations

Given a string of characters(a-z) ,find **subsequence** **such that every character is strictly greater than all previous characters** in that subsequence.

**Example** if S=abc then there are 7 subsequences which follow the above constraint. These are a,b,c,ab,ac,bc,abc. Notice that we are considering 'a' is smaller than 'b' and so on

**Note:** A subsequence is a sequence that can be derived from another sequence by deleting some elements without changing the order of the remaining elements.

We need to find number of such sequences and algo to print all such subsequences.

How to approach this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

You have a string of $n$ characters and you can form the substrings of $1, 2, \cdots, n$ characters.

The number of combinations is for the substring given by

$$ \frac{n!}{k![n-k]!} $$

So you need to calculate

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{k![n-k]!} $$

This is

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k![n-k]!}  - 1$$

Which can be written as

$$ 2^n - 1 $$

Comment: characters are not necesaarily in sorted order!! for eg s=dahy will not follow your formula

Comment: This does not seem true to me. For example, if we started with the string $S =$ "ba", then the number of increasing substrings is just $2$: namely "b" and "a" (as "ba" is not an increasing substring)

Comment: @mixedmath:yes you are right for S="ba" ans is 2

Comment: In the given example abc is a substring for the given abc...

Comment: abc is also included since b>a and c>b,c>a hence all constraints are satisfied

Comment: I now see that I did not include that condition...